# CI->session->userdata['email'] Undefined Index

Tags: codeigniter, session

**### I'm running a PHP script on Web Hosting and continue to receive errors like: ###**

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: email
>
> Filename: helpers/wpu_helper.php
>
> Line Number: 7
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   /storage/ssd5/423/13712423/public_html/application/helpers/wpu_helper.php
>   Line: 7 Function: _error_handler
>
> File:
>   /storage/ssd5/423/13712423/public_html/application/controllers/Admin.php
>   Line: 9 Function: is_logged_in
>
> File: /storage/ssd5/423/13712423/public_html/index.php Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

**helpers/wpu_helper.php**

`function is_logged_in()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();

```
if (!$CI->session->userdata['email']) {
    redirect('auth');
} else {
    $role_id    = $CI->session->userdata['role_id'];
    $menu       = $CI->uri->segment(1);

    $queryMenu  = $CI->db->get_where('user_menu', [
        'menu' => $menu
    ])->row_array();

    $menu_id = $queryMenu['id'];

    $userAccess = $CI->db->get_where('user_access_menu', [
        'role_id' => $role_id,
        'menu_id' => $menu_id
    ]);

    if ($userAccess->num_rows() < 1) {
        redirect('auth/blocked');
    }
}

function check_access($role_id, $menu_id)
{
    $CI = get_instance();

    $result = $CI->db->get_where('user_access_menu', [
        'role_id' => $role_id,
        'menu_id' => $menu_id
    ]);

    if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {
        return "checked='checked'";
    }
}
```

}`

Comment: See if using `if ( ! isset ($CI->session->userdata['email'] ) )` resolves your issue.

Comment: please try this $CI->session->userdata('email'); with using isset

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to :

```
if (!this->session->userdata('email')) {
redirect('auth');
} else {
```